# Setup NAT on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, iptables, ufw, nat

I'm trying to insert my desktop between an appliance and the rest of the network to monitor the traffic coming off of it due to some security concerns. I'd like to setup NAT so that the devices behind my testing NIC appear to be my own desktop to the rest of the network. I've tried [the information I've seen around for 10.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/firewall.html), but that doesn't seem to be working.

I'd like to stick to ufw as much as is possible because I'm trying to learn and become comfortable with the wonders that is ufw, but if it can't handle that, it's fine.

Your help in configuring this is much appreciated.

Comment: I always refer to [this article on the Gentoo wiki](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Home_Router) for this, but it uses raw `iptables`, not `ufw`. (Obviously, skip the Gentoo-specific parts.)

Answer (score 1):

ufw is not capable of doing this because it is outside of its scope. Typical iptables rules need to be implemented instead.